# tomcat 7 - @GET method with @ApplicationPath - status 404 error

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs

i want to run my project on tomcat using endpoint path
folowing are my two java files

this is my app class

```
package app;

    import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

    @ApplicationPath("/t")
    public class App extends Application{

    }
```

this is endpoint class

```
package controllers;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import dao.IEntityDAO;
import daoimpl.EntityDAOImpl;
import dto.Contacts;
import view.ContactView;

@ApplicationPath("/t1")
public class ContactController {

    @Path("/hi")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getpassword()
    {
        return "Hiii";
    }

    @Path("/t2")
    @GET()
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<ContactView> getallEntity(){

        IEntityDAO obj = new EntityDAOImpl();

        return obj.getallEntity();
    }       


}
```

my tomcat 7 is running 
But when i run it on tomcat by following path

```
http://localhost:8006/ContactApp/t/t1/hi
```

it showing following error

```
HTTP Status 404 - /ContactApp/t/t1/hi


type Status report

message /ContactApp/t/t1/hi

description The requested resource is not available.


Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

anyone can help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@ApplicationPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) may only be applied to a subclass of Application :

> Identifies the application path that serves as the base URI for all
>   resource URIs provided by Path. May only be applied to a subclass of
>   Application.

For this one :

```
@ApplicationPath("/t")
public class App extends Application{

}
```

It is fine.

But it is not the case for `ContactController` that should not declared with  `@ApplicationPath` :

```
@ApplicationPath("/t1")
public class ContactController {
```

but with [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) (without leading slash):

```
@Path("t1")
public class ContactController {
```

Extract of Path javadoc :

> Identifies the URI path that a resource class or class method will
>   serve requests for.
>   .... 
>   Paths are relative. For an annotated class the base URI is the
>   application path, see ApplicationPath.

At last, you should remove the leading slash for the `@Path` of your REST methods : `@Path("/t1")`

It is not required as the specification of `Path` explains that  leading `/`  are ignored and that base URI are handled as if a `/` was added.

> For the purposes of absolutizing a path against the base URI , a
>   leading '/' in a path is ignored and base URIs are treated as if they
>   ended in '/'

So these :

```
@Path("/hi")
...
@Path("/t2")
```

should be replaced by :

```
@Path("hi")
...
@Path("t2")
```